# vue3: inject function previously provided by different module fails

Tags: vuejs3

I have two components. This one is providing access to a rest interface:

```
<template>
  <div>This is the data creator</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import axios from "axios";
import { provide } from "vue";

const createTeam = async (teamData) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/planner/team/", teamData);
    console.log("Team created successfully:", response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating team:", error);
  }
};
provide("createTeamPush", createTeam);
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

I have a view component that is to access and use the createTeam function:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Create a new team</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm" class="needs-validation">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="teamData.name">Team Name:</label>

      </div>
      <!-- Add more input fields for other team data as needed -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Team</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import { ref } from "vue";
import { inject } from "vue";

const doCreateTeam = inject('createTeamPush');

const teamData = ref({
  name: "",
  // Add more properties for other team data as needed
});

const submitForm = async () => {
  await doCreateTeam(teamData.value);
  /* also not working:
      await this.doCreateTeam(teamData.value); */
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Add any custom styles for the form here */
</style>
```

Still the error is:

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'doCreateTeam')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'doCreateTeam')
    at submitForm (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/views/TeamCreator.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js:21:14)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1487:12)
    at callWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:296:18)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:304:17)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:437:82)
```

I watched tutorials and checked the names. I did choose different names for each stage to make it easier to see what goes wrong. The theory does not seem too complicated, but I am at a loss what I could try next to get an understanding what is missing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to recreate your error on my side. In my codebase, your example is working just fine - I only changed the api's url. The error occurs after what script command and in what context is submitForm() called?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the rest of the component, see  `<form @submit.prevent="submitForm" class="needs-validation">` in the template.

I now think that my problem is that the components are not in a parent child relation. I'm considering to use vuex.